# zsh: command not found: clear

Tags: terminal, zsh

When ever i launches a new terminal, I cannot run any basic command like clear
I have to run these first

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

And after that I can run clear command. How I can solve this issue

My zshrc is below

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$HOME/development/tooling/flutter/bin
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

Also whenever I start terminal these lines printed

```
/Users/arsl/.zshrc:10: command not found: rbenv
/Users/arsl/.zshrc:11: command not found: rbenv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
export PATH=$HOME/development/tooling/flutter/bin
```

removes all previous changes to `PATH` and sets it just to to the path to `flutter`. You need to replace this with

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/development/tooling/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: yeah this worked ... thanks